# How to determine if the user has input a hyphen?

Tags: c#, regex

There's a bunch of words that my users aren't allowed to supply for input fields. I'm catching these like so:

```
 Regex invalidWordPatten = new Regex(@"(^|\s)\b(test|unknown|as above|soos bo|na|n/a|delete|u|none|geen|0|ontbreek|nil|same as|no address available|same as)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The user is also not allowed to enter just a hyphen. I can't work out where it goes in this regular expression.

Comment: Just add `-|` at the beginning.

Comment: ...and escape the `n/a`, like this: `n\/a`

Comment: No `\/` is necessary in C#. There are no regex delimiters in .NET regex and `/` is not a special regex character.

Comment: To clarify: *No `\/` is necessary in C#* means *No escaping a forward slash is necessary in .NET regex pattern*.

Comment: @user2301328: Any feedback?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately your answer is not quite what I want. I see from your demo that it does pick up the hyphen. But a hyphen is allowed, just not only a hyphen. So for example '6 North-west St.' is fine, but just '-' is not. So I kinda want something like (test|unknown|..|-) , if you get what i'm saying ?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested: you really just need to add `-|` to the start of your pattern to also match any hyphen and - as far as I understand your code logic - if a user types a `-`, she/he will get warned:

```
-|(^|\s)\b(test|unknown|as above|soos bo|na|n/a|delete|u|none|geen|0|ontbreek|nil|same as|no address available|same as)\b
^^
```

Then, I guess you have something like

```
if (invalidWordPatten.IsMatch(input))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect input!", "Error"); // or any other handling code part
}
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-%7C(%5E%7C%5Cs)%5Cb(test%7Cunknown%7Cas%20above%7Csoos%20bo%7Cna%7Cn%2Fa%7Cdelete%7Cu%7Cnone%7Cgeen%7C0%7Contbreek%7Cnil%7Csame%20as%7Cno%20address%20available%7Csame%20as)%5Cb&i=-%20testing&o=x)

Answer (score -1):

You can create another RegEx to check hyphen char, it would help your code clean and easy to read:

```
Regex hyphenChar = new Regex(@"\b[^-]+\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex invalidWordPatten = new Regex(@"(^|\s)\b(test|unknown|as above|soos bo|na|n/a|delete|u|none|geen|0|ontbreek|nil|same as|no address available|same as)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var isNotMatch = hyphenChar.Match(...) && invalidWordPatten.Match(...)
```